# Is it possible to get an approximation to a seed based on a finite sequence of pseudo random numbers?

Tags: algorithm, random, srand

suppose I have some numbers that form a series 
for example: 652,328,1,254
and I want to get a seed that if I, for example, do

```
srand(my_seed);
```

I will get some kind of approximation with bounded error to my origonal sequence,
when all numbers appearing in the same order.

Comment: nothing for now , just for curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the algorithm used for the pseudo-random generation. If the algorithm is a simple [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), then getting the seed back is just a matter of solving a linear modular equation (note that the solution may be non-unique, but as such a generator is memory-less, it doesn't matter).

If the algorithm is more complex, this may be impossible.

Note that the algorithm used in the C standard library isn't restricted by the standard, so different platforms may have different implementations.

Comment: Not only does the algorithm have to be simple enough to analyze; it also has to have enough bits of state to encode the series you want to reproduce. The combination seems unlikely in practice. For example, I think you can configure glibc to use an LCG by calling `setstate` with a small enough buffer; but then that LCG only has 32 bits of state, so at best you can choose the first 32 bits of output. Everything after that is deterministic.

Comment: More directly: if `srand` takes a 32-bit argument on your platform, you can ask for at most 2^32 different sequences. But of course there are far more possible sequences than that, even if you only want to reproduce a very short sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343324/find-out-what-a-random-number-generator-was-seeded-with-in-c).

Like Justin says, it's possible to backtrack a linear congruent generator (which `rand()` implementations often are) when you have a sequence of generated numbers. I guess the problem is to know which one of the previous values is the original seed...

Comment: [citation needed] - where's the requirement that `rand()` is an LCG i.e. bad?

Comment: I don't thinks there's any requirement for `rand()` to be and LCG, that's just what most implementations seem to be (I've edited the answer to be more clear about this). Also, and LCG isn't necessarily bad - it's very quick to compute and in many cases the provided pseudo-randomness is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an error bound in general. Either your algorithm works or it doesn't. The reason for this is that a reasonable error bound is obviously much smaller that RAND_MAX. That in turn means that the the low bits are not as random as the higher bits. But a good PRNG makes certain that all bits are equally random.

Consider this slow but mathematically sound example of an RNG algorithm:

```
int rand() {
  state = AES_encrypt(state);
  return state % RAND_MAX;
}
void srand(int seed) {
  state = AES_encrypt(seed);
}
```

If you can find any significant correlation between the output sequence and the previous `state`, the AES algorithm should be considered broken.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a crytographic PRNG is one in which this exact property is computationally infeasible - however, as has been mentioned, there are much weaker (and much faster) PRNGs for which this is possible.  So it depends on your algorithm.